# FlowLayoutPanel FlowDirection issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, design-patterns, flowlayoutpanel

I'm trying to add x Buttons to a FlowLayoutPanel which is docked (DocType fill) in a Panel.
I have set the FlowDirection to Topdown as I want something like:
[image: this]

However, the FlowLayoutPanel has a horizontal scrollbar, not a vertical one:
[image: See here]

I add the buttons like this:

```
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Button { Text = "Chat", Width = flowLayoutPanel1.Width - flowLayoutPanel1.Margin.Left - flowLayoutPanel1.Margin.Right});
```

I also tried:

```
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Button { Text = "Chat", Dock = DockStyle.Fill});
```

And also:

```
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Button { Text = "Chat", Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right});
```

I tried [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-anchor-and-dock-child-controls-in-a-flowlayoutpanel-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) and also looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57921906/winforms-flowlayoutpanel-flowdirection-topdown-and-scroll-vertically). Both don't work for me.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried to set the FLP's `FlowDirection = LeftToRight`? (TopDown = from Top until the Bottom is reached, then start over)

Comment: A suggestion: set the FLP's `Padding` to `All = 0` and use the child Control's `Margin` to setup their layout inside the FLP. Assuming their Margin is set to `All = 3`, then the Width of the child Controls is `[FLP].Width - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth - [Child].Padding.Left * 2 - 2`

Answer (score 2):

after some digging [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441658/winforms-flowlayoutpanel-with-docking) I found it out.
I had to set the [FlowLayoutPanel.WrapContents Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.wrapcontents?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-6.0#System_Windows_Forms_FlowLayoutPanel_WrapContents) to false.